# Wordpress Permalinks does not redirect links in my new theme

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, themes, permalinks

I hope you can help me.
I'm using /%postname%/ as permalink structure, and my .htaccess is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the default theme everything working fine but in the theme that i need to use, default link '?p=123' does not redirect to the 'Post Name' link, and both links are working at the same time, I'm not sure what should i do! please help me.
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking. Have you just uploaded your site to another server? If so, then you just need to go to Settings > Permalinks and hit the update button. It will work then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No i just tested in my localhost and problem was the same!
Default theme works fine, i also have another Wordpress on the same host and that works fine too, i really don't know what i have to do!

Comment: Your .htaccess looks fine. Have you tried switching from postname back to the default permalink settngs. Updated then switched back? Is a very strange issue and without seeing what Default vs Current theme is will be hard to deduce.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to flush the rewrite rules.

```
/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'bt_flush_rewrite_rules' );

/* Flush your rewrite rules */
function bt_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

If it doesn't work, it means that there is any function to prevent the redirection on the theme.

Comment: thank you for your help.
do i have to use in my functions.php !? if yes, i did and i switched my theme but nothing changed!

Comment: When you active the custom theme, all permalinks don't work or just some of them don't work?

Comment: same issue on other permalinks, ugly and pretty links both are working but i need just pretty links, and i have this issue only in my custom theme!

Comment: After you active your theme, select "Default" on the permalink settings page. Then see the pretty links work or not. 
Then change the permalink settings to "Post Name" and check again.

Comment: in my custom theme, when i select "Default" permalink, just "Default" links works i mean the ugly one, but in "Post Name" permalinks, both works "Default" and "Post Name" at the same time.